# How to check efficiently if in number binary representation all next bit is different?

Tags: binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I need to write the function to check if the number binary representation doesn't contain duplications. For example, the function must return **true** if **N** equals to **42**, because **bin(42)** equals to **101010**, but if **N** equals to **45** the function must return **false**, because of binary representation of **45** which equals to **101101** and which contains duplicates **11**.

Comment: What about 100101, are adjacent 0's also forbidden?

Comment: @FalkHüffner Yes. The same for zeros.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This allows only bits that alternate between 0 and 1, plus possibly leading zeros.

One way to check this is to look at `(N << 2) | N`. If `N` is of the correct form, then this is equal to `N << 2`, except for bit 0 or 1. We can compensate for that as follows:

```
unsigned N2 = N << 2;
return (N | N2) <= (N2 | 2);
```

Comment: Thank you for saving my time.